# readyState==3 no funciona

Tags: javascript, ajax

Buen dia,

En mi código todo funciona perfectamente excepto el readyState==3, se supone que en ese estado se esta enviando la información al .php y me debería mostrar el 'cargando...' en el div, mas abajo cuando esta en estado 4 y respuesta 200 si me muestra en el div el resultado,

como podría solucionar lo del estado 3?

Gracias!

```
function consultar_solicitudes(str){

  if (str==""){
   //borro el div por si hay algo en el 
    document.getElementById("div_para_tabla").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (this.readyState==3)
    {
//aqui dentro del if no me funciona esto
      document.getElementById("div_para_tabla").innerHTML="Cargando...";
    }

    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
{
// aqui funciona perfectamente
      document.getElementById("div_para_tabla").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","../PHP/consultar_solicitudes.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Puede ser que si funcione pero que sea muy rapido, puedes probar con un alert para ver si ese es el caso

Comment: `console.log(this.readyState)` antes del primer `if` te puede dar pistas de que está pasando, sino la solución sería poner el `cargando` justo antes de hacer la petición y reemplazarlo por un fail si falla